# In Rust, how does Weak<T> know when the inner value has been dropped?

Tags: rust, memory-management, smart-pointers, weak-references, reference-counting

`std::rc::Weak<T>` has the following definition:

```rust
pub struct Weak<T: ?Sized> {
    ptr: NonNull<RcBox<T>>,
}
```

In my understanding, when there's no more `Rc<T>` left, `RcBox<T>` will be freed and `Weak<T>.ptr` now points to a place that could potentially contain anything. So when `upgrade()` is called on a `Weak<T>`, how does it know the pointer is now invalid?

`Weak<T>::upgrade` has the following implementation:

```rust
    pub fn upgrade(&self) -> Option<Rc<T>> {
        let inner = self.inner()?;

        if inner.strong() == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            unsafe {
                inner.inc_strong();
                Some(Rc::from_inner(self.ptr))
            }
        }
    }
```

Does this imply `RcBox<T>` is not really freed when there's no `Rc<T>` left in the wild? If so, wouldn't that leak memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `RcBox` is not destroyed until there are no strong *or* weak pointers remaining.

However, the contained `T` is [dropped in place](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.69.0/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#1593) when the strong count reaches zero.  This effectively destroys the contained `T` but does not release the memory of the `T` itself.  This is how `Weak` knows if the inner value was dropped -- if you try to upgrade a `Weak` to an `Rc` when the strong count is zero, the operation fails and returns `None`.

Once the weak count also reaches zero, the `RcBox` itself is freed.  So no, there is no memory leak.

Note that many types (such as `String` and `Vec`) manage a separate heap allocation.  If you have an `Rc<Vec<_>>`, for example, when the strong count reaches zero but the weak count does not, the drop code for the inner `Vec` runs and drops all of its owned elements as well as frees the heap allocation used to store them.  The memory used by the `Vec` itself to hold the heap pointer, length, and capacity is *not* freed as it is owned by the `RcBox`.  That allocation is only freed when the strong and weak counts both reach zero.

Comment: This is how `Weak` makes cycle possible, because the drop of the `Rc` will cause the `Weak` to be dropped.